# How to reduce the width of the line on a LineChart

Tags: java, javafx, linechart

I've been attempting to plot a line chart, and right now I have around 2,000 data points I'd like to map.

The problem is, with the line's thickness the data clarity gets rather fudged.

I've already set the chart symbols to false.

Is there any way for me to have direct control over the thickness of the lines?

Oddly enough, the data looked much more clear when I had been using an area chart. I may just switch back to using that if there doesn't seem to be any discernible way to reduce the size.

Comment: Did you try the CSS property `.chart-series-line {-fx-stroke-width: 1px;}` ?

Comment: @Pagbo didn't know about that! I tried that that and it works just like I wanted. Thanks!